# What am I missing on this part of the documentation?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, documentation

In the documentation for *FullSimplify*, under *Options > Assumptions* it is stated that:

> *When assumptions are given as an argument, $Assumptions is used as well:*
>
> ```
> Assuming[x > 0, FullSimplify[E^(LogGamma[x] + LogGamma[y]), y > 0]]
> (* Gamma[x] Gamma[y] *)
> ```
>
> *Specifying assumptions as an option value prevents FullSimplify from using $Assumptions:*
>
> ```
> Assuming[x > 0, FullSimplify[E^(LogGamma[x] + LogGamma[y]), Assumptions -> y > 0]]
> (* Gamma[x] Gamma[y] *)
> ```

The resuls are just the same. What is the point?

```
$Version
(* 10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015) *)
```

Comment: Try `FullSimplify[E^(LogGamma[x] + LogGamma[y])]` without assumptions.

Comment: I get the same result.

Comment: So the assumptions are irrelevant, since the simplification is valid more generally.

Comment: This documentation example just adds nothing then.

Comment: Yes, it's strange.  I wonder if it has changed since some version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a badly written example. What it is trying to show is something like the following behavior, where the local `Assumptions` option overrides the global `$Assumptions`.

```
$Assumptions = x == -1;
FullSimplify[E^(LogGamma[x] + LogGamma[y])]
```

> FullSimplify::infd : "Expression LogGamma[x] + LogGamma[y] simplified to ∞.
>
> ```
> ∞
> ```

```
FullSimplify[E^(LogGamma[x] + LogGamma[y]), Assumptions -> x == 1]
```

> ```
> Gamma[y]
> ```

However, `Assumming` only adds to `$Assumptions`, so

```
Assuming[x == 1, FullSimplify[E^(LogGamma[x] + LogGamma[y])]]
```

produces

> $Assumptions::cas : Warning : 
>      contradictory assumption (s) x == 1 && x == -1 encountered. >>
>
> ```
> 1
> ```